# how to access linux machine behind the nat route, using router IP and some port number

Tags: ubuntu, port-forwarding, iptables, nat

```
 ---                    ------                    -------- 
|PC|       <-->        |router|             <-->  |linux pc|
----                    ------                     --------
```

PC IP 192.168.10.5

router ip (left interface) 192.168.10.1

router ip (right interface) 192.168.45.1

linux PC ip 192.168.45.5

i am on PC(192.168.10.5) and from there i want to ssh to 192.168.45.5, but using only router IP 192.168.10.1 with some port number.

any knows how to configure router using Iptables????
all machine have ubuntu running in them.

Comment: Is the router also running ubuntu? It that's the case you can just ssh to it and ssh to the linux pc afterwards. If it's a normal router you can NAT the desired port in it's software

Comment: yes router is also running ubuntu. i can ssh to router and from there i can also ssh to right most pc. But i want to use only 192.168.10.1 ip attaching some port to reach the right most PC. could you tell me what linux(ubuntu) commands do i need to feed in the router in order to make this task possible??

Comment: Check this https://serverfault.com/questions/140622/how-can-i-port-forward-with-iptables

Comment: Is this a regular routed setup or is the router doing NAT? This is a critical difference.

Answer (score 1):

i am closing this question, as i am able to access 192.168.45.5 using routers 192.168.10.1 ip with port 20022

iptables --table nat -A PREROUTING -i enp2s0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 20022 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.45.30:22

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o enp2s0 -j MASQUERADE

iptables -A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

iptables -A FORWARD -i enp3s0 -o enp2s0 -j ACCEPT

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've enabled port forwarding in `/etc/sysctl.conf`. If so, this would help with your corresponding interface name.

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth1 -j MASQUERADE 

iptables -A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth1 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: This doesn’t provide a solution to the question. Instead, it just enables NAT. You also don’t enable port forwarding in sysctl. The setting there is about acting as a router.